# I made a javascript function and now I want to shorten it, how do I do that?

Tags: javascript

My code is way too long and I wondered if someone could show me how to shorten it?

This is the code I'm talking about:

```
function load_home() {
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="home.html" ></object>';
}

function load_famous() {
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="famous.html" ></object>';
}

function load_game() {
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="game.html" ></object>';
}

function load_color() {
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="color.html" ></object>';
}

function load_other() {
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="other.html" ></object>';
}
```

EDIT:

I can't seem to get any of them working and if I place the code at the bottom of the page only the last page loads.

I think it has something to do with my onclick so this is what it looks like now (just the home page):

```
onclick="load_home()"
```

I also tried a external js file but that didn't help either, sorry if this is noob stuff.

Comment: Extract the parts that are common. `function load_home () { load_data("home"); }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a parameter indicating the `data` you need instead:

```
function loadObject(data) {
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = `<object type="text/html" data="${data}.html" ></object>`;
}
```

Then you can use `loadObject('home')`, `loadObject('famous')`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can use function arguments. Since all your code is basically the same thing but different links, you can just pass different arguments in.

Try using this:

```
function load(data) {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=`<object type="text/html" data="${data}.html" ></object>`;
}
let datas = ["home", "famous", "color", "game", "other"];
datas.forEach(i => {
    load(i);
});
```

For more information on function arguments, read [this site].(https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Shortest yet...

```
function load_any(Type){content.innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="'+Type+'.html"></object>';}
```

Usage...

```
load_any('game');
```